# How to return records in MySQL with "custom" ordering

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to return records based on their IDs in MySQL without ordering.

But when I run the query it will order them from the lowest ID number to highest one.

`SELECT * FROM events WHERE id=11 or id=4 or id=9 or id=5`

The result will like these: 4,5,9,11

How can return like this : 11,4,9,5

Comment: A little off topic, but you can consolidate these where clauses into `WHERE id IN (11, 4, 9, 5)`. The order that they appear in the WHERE does not affect the order they return in, though others have some good tips on how to order them the way you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using `ORDER BY FIELD (id, ...)`:

```
SELECT *
FROM events
WHERE id IN (4, 5, 9, 11)
ORDER BY FIELD (id, 11, 4, 9, 5)
```

### Demo

As to why your current query is showing the `4,5,9,11` order, even without your using an explicit `ORDER BY` clause, one explanation is that the `id` column is the clustered primary key for your table.  In that case, the data would actually be stored in this order on disk, and when selecting, this would be the natural order returned.

**Edit:**

On other database vendors, which don't support `FIELD`, we can order using a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT *
FROM events
WHERE id IN (4, 5, 9, 11)
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN id = 11 THEN 1
         WHEN id = 4  THEN 2
         WHEN id = 9  THEN 3
         WHEN id = 5  THEN 4
         ELSE 5 END;
```

Comment: It make returns randomly each time when I run the query an It is not fixed

Comment: Sorry, I misread your requirement.  Try using `ORDER BY FIELD (id, ...)`.

Answer (score 6):

I believe you want to use [`FIELD()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field)

```
SELECT * FROM events WHERE id=11 or id=4 or id=9 or id=5
ORDER BY FIELD(id, 11,4,8,5)
```

Or the more ANSI SQL method (works also for other databases vendors)

```
SELECT 
 events.*
FROM (
  SELECT 
     11 AS id
   , 1 AS position
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
     4 AS id
   , 2 AS position
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
     8 AS id
   , 3 AS position 
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 
     5 AS id
   , 4 AS position 
) AS sorting
INNER JOIN 
 events 
ON
 sorting.id = events.id
ORDER BY 
 sorting.position ASC
```

**Or the better ANSI SQL like it should** (works also for other databases vendors)

```
SELECT * FROM events WHERE id=11 or id=4 or id=9 or id=5
ORDER BY CASE WHEN id = 11 THEN 1
              WHEN id = 4 THEN 2
              WHEN id = 8 THEN 3
              WHEN id = 5 THEN 4
              ELSE 5
         END
```

Comment: "The replacement for FIELD in other database is really CASE, not a union query." indeed but the union also works @TimBiegeleisen `CASE WHEN id = 11 THEN 1 WHEN id = 4 THEN 2 WHEN id = 8 THEN 4 WHEN id = 5 THEN 4 ELSE 5 END` is indeed more easy it's late over here blame it to that

Comment: New Year's Eve surprise +1.  It's already 1-Jan where I live :-)

Comment: got my New Year's best to y'all too ;-)

Answer (score 2):

** Updateded
As you want fixed order, you can use ORDER BY FIELD :

```
SELECT * FROM events
WHERE id IN (4, 5, 9, 11)
ORDER BY FIELD (id, 11, 4, 9, 5)
```

Comment: The OP wants a fixed order, see the comments under my answer.

Comment: Not sure why this is upvoted.. because this not match the topic starter requirements.